# WinHTTP Request data in unicode?

Tags: c++, html, unicode, winhttp

I'm trying to read a web page via WinHTTP:

```
bool WinHTTPClass::QueryResponseData(std::string &query_data)
{
    // Read response

    DWORD dwSize, dwDownloaded = 0;

    do 
    {
        // Check for available data.  

        if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize ) )
        {
            cout << "Error querying data : " << GetLastError() << endl;
            return false;
        }

        // Allocate space for the buffer.

        char* pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];

        if( !pszOutBuffer )
        {
            cout << "Out of memory" << endl;
            dwSize=0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Read the data.
            ZeroMemory( pszOutBuffer, dwSize+1 );

            if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, 
                                dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
            {
                cout << "Error reading data : " << GetLastError() << endl;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                query_data += pszOutBuffer;
            }

            // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
            delete [] pszOutBuffer;
        }
    }
    while( dwSize > 0 );

    return true;
}
```

All this works well. The confusion I am having here is that should I handle the buffer data using unicode encoding buffer instead of:

```
char* pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize+1];
```

By such as using `wchar_t` instead the web pages commonly use UTF8? What's the difference? Where am I confused?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is a binary transport, it has no concept of text or Unicode.  HTTP uses 7bit ASCII for HTTP headers, but content is arbitrary binary data whose interpretation is dependent on the HTTP headers that describe it, most notably the `Content-Type` header.  So you need to receive the raw content data into your `char[]` buffer first, then look at the received `Content-Type` header using [`WinHttpQueryHeaders()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see what kind of data you received.  If it says you received a `text/...` type then the header will usually also specify the `charset` of the text. In the case of `text/html`, the `charset` may be in a `<meta>` tag within the HTML itself instead of in the HTTP header.  Once you know the `charset` of the text, you can then convert it to `wchar_t[]` using [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (you will have to manually lookup the appropriate codepage for the charset).