# Is there a way to send a POST through WinHttpSendRequest(); with the unicode representation of characters ie: \u0420?

Tags: c++, c, unicode, winhttp

I need to send a UTF-8 string with Unicode characters in it to a web API from a c/c++ application, I am sending it with a Content-Type of application/json.

For example I have a string that is "щь".

Currently what sends is the ASCII representation (each individual byte) "Ñ‰ÑŒ"

However I would like it to send the Unicode number instead "\u0449\u044c"

Is there a way to do this using WinHTTPRequest?

Comment: Not a duplicate because it seems to be going the other way, but could have useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21503314/10957435

Comment: @Chipster Thanks I'll take a look!

Comment: Regrettably the method employed in that post does not work for this situation. Converting the multi byte I currently have have to a wide string and Posting it through WinHttpSendRequest results in malformed characters in the request.

Comment: `"Ñ‰ÑŒ"` is the correct UTF-8 encoded form of `"щь"`, just misinterpreted as Latin-1 instead of UTF-8. The actual raw bytes are correct. WinHTTP sends whatever bytes you give it, make sure to specify `charset=utf-8` in your `Content-Type` request header. If the server ends up with `"Ñ‰ÑŒ"` instead of `"щь"` when parsing the data then it is not interpreting the UTF-8 properly. That is not a problem on your client side. Otherwise, simply re-format your JSON string to use explicit `"\uXXXX"` encoded substrings instead of raw Unicode chars, eg: `"field": "\u0449\u044C"` instead of `"field": "щь"`.

Comment: The JSON string that I am using is dynamically, do you know if there is a way to retrieving or converting to the unicode number (\u0449) from the "щь" or "Ñ‰ÑŒ"

Comment: @Steven that is a feature of JSON, so find a JSON library that outputs what you want. Or simply parse the JSON yourself to convert it as desired. Either way, this issue has nothing to do with WinHTTP at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your help! I have been able to get it working now.